# How to create an abstract constructor or get type of abstract class and return it?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, json.net, abstract-class

I can't get the method or a constructor inside of my abstract class working correctly.

I essentially have several data contract classes that extend my abstract class and have a simple, nearly identical method inside of them that I'm trying to figure out how to move to my abstract class.

I'm pretty sure a constructor makes the most sense, but I can't figure out the proper syntax. To use it currently, I call something like this:

> `OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();`
>
> `orderLine = orderLine.createFromJsonString("MyJsonString");`

I'm trying to move the methods marked (1) and (2) into the (0) position as either a method or constructor.

```
abstract class Pagination<T>
{
    public int _offset { get; set; }
    public int _total { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public abstract List<T> items { get; set; }

    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items != null ? items.Count() : 0;
    }

    // (0)
    // Each of the child objects that extend this class are created from
    // a Json that is deserialized. So I'd rather some method that would
    // construct or return a new instance of the abstract object 
    /*
    public object createFromJsonString(string _json)
    {
     * // The main issue here is the "this" keyword
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<this>(_json);
    }
     **/
    
}

class OrderHeader : Pagination<OrderLine>
{
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> items { get; set; }

    // (1)
    // How can I move this into the abstract class?
    // Or should it be written as constructor?
    public OrderHeader createFromJsonString(string _json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderHeader>(_json);
    }
}

class OrderLine : Pagination<OrderLineDetails>
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLineDetails> items { get; set; }

    // (2)
    // How can I move this into the abstract class?
    // Or should it be written as constructor?
    public OrderLine createFromJsonString(string _json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderLine>(_json);
    }
}

class OrderLineDetails
{
    public string serialNum { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are doing few things incorrectly:

```
// You have created object once here, this object would become unused in next line
OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();

// Here you are building a new object via Deserialize
orderLine = orderLine.createFromJsonString("MyJsonString");
```

What I understood from your question is you want to have a factory method to create objects of derived types of Pagination<>.

```
abstract class Pagination<T>
{
    public int _offset { get; set; }
    public int _total { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public abstract List<T> items { get; set; }

    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items != null ? items.Count() : 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Factory method to build the pagination object from Json string.
    /// </summary>
    public static TCurrent CreateFromJsonString<TCurrent>(string _json) where TCurrent: Pagination<T>
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TCurrent>(_json);
    }
}
```

Now you can build the object of Derived types like:

```
 OrderHeader hdr = Pagination<OrderLine>.CreateFromJsonString<OrderHeader>(json);

 OrderLine line = Pagination<OrderLineDetails>.CreateFromJsonString<OrderLine>(json);
```

The factory method also prevent doing something like below because we have applied generic constraints so that only relevant items types are allowed.

```
// This will throw error of invalid implicit conversion
OrderHeader invalidObj = Pagination<OrderLineDetails>.CreateFromJsonString<OrderHeader>(json);
```

Comment: although at that point you wonder what's more useful :)
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` or `Pagination<T>.CreateFromJsonString<TCurrent>(json)`

Comment: Thanks so much! A lot to take in.

Comment: @jacob There's not much difference. But the factory method introduced with a wrapper with constraint and it would help in consistency of object creations. Your answer was also a way of doing it. :)

Comment: Is there an easy way I could do this with an abstract constructor?

Comment: No.. Constructor executes during object creation means when the Deserialize method will try to create the object then only the abstract constructor will execute. Constructors can only be used to populate the members/properties with default or supplied information. It can not create object of it's own type.

Comment: Ah that makes sense why I was struggling so much trying to make a constructor for it.